# Add columns in a data frame whose column headers are unique values of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure if this particular type of question has been answered before. I did a lot of research but couldn't get exactly what I wanted. I have a data set with many columns. Two of the columns are Organic = c("Yes","Yes","No",...) and StoreBrand = c("No","Yes","No",...). I want to create columns having headers Organic_Yes, Organic_No, StoreBrand_Yes and StoreBrand_No and fill them with 0 and 1. So my expected output will be

| Organic | Organic_Yes | Organic_No | StoreBrand | StoreBrand_Yes | StoreBrand_No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 1 | 0 | No | 0 | 1 |
| Yes | 1 | 0 | Yes | 1 | 0 |
| No | 0 | 1 | No | 0 | 1 |

.....etc. I want to do this in R. Any help is appreciated

It would be great if the new column headers are not created by brute force. I am looking to automate the process of creating these columns. Thanks again!

Comment: (1) Look for questions with something like `model.matrix`, as that might be enough to do (most of) this. (2) Providing expected output is good, please [edit] your question and add your starting data as well (same format is fine in this case).

Comment: @r2evans Is there a tidyverse approach?

Comment: Possibly, find the `model.matrix` answers and you'll likely find same-page answers that suggest tidyverse approaches. They're usually slower and/or many more lines of code, but that's a cost of insisting on tidyverse over base-R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach: Using `across` twice with manipulating the `.names` argument (learned here: [Using a function in .names argument of across function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669236/using-a-function-in-names-argument-of-across-function/69669305#69669305))

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. == "Yes", 1, 0), .names ="{.col}_Yes"),
         across(contains("Yes"), ~ifelse(. == 1, 0, 1), .names = "{str_replace(.col,'_Yes', '_No')}"))
```

output:

```
  Organic StoreBrand Organic_Yes StoreBrand_Yes Organic_No StoreBrand_No
1     Yes         No           1              0          0             1
2     Yes        Yes           1              1          0             0
3      No         No           0              0          1             1
```

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple tidyverse approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Organic_Yes = as.numeric(Organic == "Yes"),
         Organic_No = 1 - Organic_Yes,
         Storebrand_Yes = as.numeric(StoreBrand == "Yes"),
         Storebrand_No = 1 - Storebrand_Yes) %>%
  select(Organic, Organic_Yes, Organic_No,
         StoreBrand, Storebrand_Yes, Storebrand_No)

#>   Organic Organic_Yes Organic_No StoreBrand Storebrand_Yes Storebrand_No
#> 1     Yes           1          0         No              0             1
#> 2     Yes           1          0        Yes              1             0
#> 3      No           0          1         No              0             1
```

Or a more general tidyverse approach:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), 
                function(x) 1 * (x == "Yes"),
                .names = "{.col}_Yes")) %>%
  mutate(across(tidyselect::vars_select_helpers$where(is.character),
                function(x) 1 * (x == "No"),
                .names = "{.col}_No")) %>%
  select(order(names(.)))

#>   Organic Organic_No Organic_Yes StoreBrand StoreBrand_No StoreBrand_Yes
#> 1     Yes          0           1         No             1              0
#> 2     Yes          0           1        Yes             0              1
#> 3      No          1           0         No             1              0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(Organic    = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"),
                 StoreBrand = c("No", "Yes", "No"))

df
#>   Organic StoreBrand
#> 1     Yes         No
#> 2     Yes        Yes
#> 3      No         No
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow, way to brute-force it AllanCameron :-)

Comment: Can the column headers be automated in R. So like paste("Organic","_", "Yes")?

Comment: @DebasmitaDas yes, see my edit

Comment: @r2evans yes, a bit lazy that. I added a general approach to expunge the guilt.