# Using a function in .names argument of across function

Tags: r, dplyr, across

In this example dataset I would like to be able to manipulate the `.names` argument in the second `mutate(across...` part:

In particluar I would like to manipulate `{.col}` with a function like `sub`.

In essence:
I would like to remove the `greater4` string in the last two columns:

`Sepal.Length_greater4_greater50` and `Sepal.Width_greater4_greater50` to

`Sepal.Length_greater50` and `Sepal.Width_greater50`

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)
head(iris, 5) %>% 
  select(1,2) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("Sepal"), ~ifelse(. > 4, 1, 0), .names = "{.col}_greater4")) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("4"), ~ifelse(. < 50, 1, 0), .names = "{.col}_greater50"))

Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Sepal.Length_greater4 Sepal.Width_greater4 Sepal.Length_greater4_greater50 Sepal.Width_greater4_greater50
1          5.1         3.5                     1                    0                               1                              1
2          4.9         3.0                     1                    0                               1                              1
3          4.7         3.2                     1                    0                               1                              1
4          4.6         3.1                     1                    0                               1                              1
5          5.0         3.6                     1                    0                               1                              1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_replace` within the `{}`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
 head(iris, 5) %>% 
  select(1,2) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("Sepal"), ~ifelse(. > 4, 1, 0), 
      .names = "{.col}_greater4")) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("4"), ~ifelse(. < 50, 1, 0), 
    .names = "{str_replace(.col, '_greater4', '_greater50')}"))
```

-output

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Sepal.Length_greater4 Sepal.Width_greater4 Sepal.Length_greater50 Sepal.Width_greater50
1          5.1         3.5                     1                    0                      1                     1
2          4.9         3.0                     1                    0                      1                     1
3          4.7         3.2                     1                    0                      1                     1
4          4.6         3.1                     1                    0                      1                     1
5          5.0         3.6                     1                    0                      1                     1
```

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69668773/add-columns-in-a-data-frame-whose-column-headers-are-unique-values-of-another-co/69669381#69669381>

Comment: @Tarjae Does it work for you

Comment: It worked perfect fine @akrun. many thank!